# Restore Point Informations Veeam PowerShell

Tags: powershell, csv, restore, veeam, restore-points

I want to get informations about the restore points of a vm.
I have a list with the names of each vm in a CSV.

I want to know for each restore Point the **name of the VM**, which **Media Pool** it is, which **Media Set** and the **backup set date**. 
I Could not find any veeam-cmdlet which could help me.

I tried it with

```
$ImportCSV = Import-csv $VMNames
    $Days = 10
    $DateToCompare = (Get-date).AddDays(-$Days) 
        $ImportCSV | % {
            Get-VBRRestorePoint -Name $_.Name |
                Where-Object { $_.CreationTime -gt $DateToCompare }
        } | Select-Object VMName
```

But then i could not find the informations i am looking for on the return values of `Get-VBRRestorePoint`
Does anyone know the right cmdlets? Couldn't find anything on Google.
The Result should be exported as a csv File.

Comment: Instead of `Select-Object`, try using `Get-Member -MemberType Property` to figure out what you need to grab off the `RestorePoint` object.

Comment: Can you explain why `Get-Member` is better than `Select-Object`? I don't understand the difference (as you see i am a PowerShell Beginner)

Comment: If I recall correctly I already suggested using `Get-Member` (as well as `Format-List *`) in my comment to your previous, now deleted, question. You use the former cmdlet, because its purpose is to provide information about the members (properties and methods) of an object (`Get-VBRRestorePoint ... | Get-Member`). Which is exactly the information you're looking for.